# post_migrate for only specific app

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-migrations

I want to run database comments(on columns and tables) in postgres tables every time I do syncdb. For this, I've written comment commands in SQL files for each Django app. Since syncdb is deprecated in Django 1.8, I'll go with migrate. So, I've set up post_migrate signal, but I want it to be specific to the app.

For example, when I run `python manage.py migrate <app_name>`, it should run comments for that particular file. Here's my code:

```
class CreateComments(AppConfig):
    name = 'app_name'
    def ready(self):
        signals.post_migrate.connect(create_comments, sender=self, weak=False)


def create_comments(sender, **kwargs):
    full_path = settings.PROJECT_BASE_PATH + 'sql/app_name_comments.sql'
    sql_file = open(full_path, 'r')
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql_file.read())
    print 'app_name Comment Applied '
```

I've written this in 2 apps. So when I run `python manage.py migrate app_name1`, it runs the function for both the apps.

Is there some way I can make this app-specific? Do mention if I'm not making myself clear.

Comment: Trying to achieve same goal right now. Did you manage to do it ?